# Can I replace multiple volatile reads with one given all of them are executed within ReentrantLock.lock()/unlock()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

I'm looking into the [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java) of `ConcurrentReferenceHashMap` in Spring Framework, particularly into `restructure()` [method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8f96ca4a2d82607a511dbb5b5e10e9f1c43ebe54/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java#L580):

```java
protected final class Segment extends ReentrantLock {

    private volatile Reference<K, V>[] references; // <-- !

    private void restructure(boolean allowResize, @Nullable Reference<K, V> ref) {
        boolean needsResize;
        lock();
        try {
            //...
            boolean resizing = false;
            int restructureSize = this.references.length; // <-- !
            //...

            Reference<K, V>[] restructured =
                    (resizing ? createReferenceArray(restructureSize) : this.references);// <-- !

            for (int i = 0; i < this.references.length; i++) { // <-- !
                ref = this.references[i]; // <-- !
                //...
            }

            if (resizing) {
                this.references = restructured;
                this.resizeThreshold = (int) (this.references.length * getLoadFactor());// <-- !
            }
            //...
        }
        finally {
            unlock();
        }
    }
```

As you can see here we have multiple reads and writes into volatile `references` array and all of them happen within `lock()/unlock()` synchronization block.

The [JavaDoc of java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html), namely its `Memory Synchronization` part claims, that

> All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in Chapter 17 of The Java™ Language Specification:
>
> - A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Lock action.
> - A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Unlock action.

> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory synchronization effects.

My question is: can I rewrite the code in order to have one read from volatile field into a local var (i.e. synchronize on stack) and use it to avoid repeating volatile access? Won't it break JMM assuming that

> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory synchronization effects.

Comment: its interesting that if you look at `getReference` method, they do copy that locally; but there the method is not protected by a lock so the comment `// Use a local copy to protect against other threads writing` does make sense.

Comment: I would need to look a lot more carefully at that code, because if there is a method that _writes_ to that `references` _without_ using that same lock, than two reads in `restructure` of that `references` can yield to two difference results. Specifically `int restructureSize = this.references.length;` and `int i = 0; i < this.references.length; i++` can have different values. It seems very dangerous what they are doing, to me. But again, need to look and reason about this a lot more closely.

Comment: This looks like being derived from pre-Java 8 `ConcurrentHashMap`. Instead of thinking about micro-optimizations like this, redesigning it the way, Java 8 did with the original, would have a far bigger advantage.

Comment: @Holger yeah, this is a very outdated copy-paste from JDK. Indeed, it's better to use current edition of the code, and my question is more about understanding what can be optimized ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my answer to the additional question in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286204/can-i-replace-multiple-volatile-reads-with-one-given-all-of-them-are-executed-wi#comment122476441_69289972):

> I don't understand the race here: writing into `references` within restructure() is guarded by lock()-unlock() block, so it happens-before read from `references` in getReference(), doesn't it? And vice-versa: reading from `references` in getReference() "sees" only the last (in terms of execution within lock-unlock) writing into `references`, doesn't it?

Few notes first:

- > ... writing into `references` within restructure() is guarded by lock()-unlock() block, so it happens-before read from `references` in getReference() ...

  That is not true.

  `lock()-unlock()` block provides happens-before and atomicity guarantees only to other `lock()-unlock()` blocks (and they must use the same `Lock` object).

  The read in `getReference()` is not inside `lock()-unlock()`, so it can happen in parallel with another thread writing something inside `restructure()` method.
- > ... reading from `references` in getReference() "sees" only the last (in terms of execution within lock-unlock) writing into `reference` ...

  `references` (I am talking here about the `reference` which is an instance field in `Segment`, not the local variable with the same name in `getReference()`) is a `volatile` field, and, as a result, all reads and writes to this field happens in a global order ([synchronization order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4), one per execution, can be different in different executions), and every read of `references` always sees the latest write to it.

  It's important to understand that:

  - only `references` field (which stores reference to `Reference<K, V>[]` object) is volatile, not the `Reference<K, V>[]` object itself
  - reads and writes of an array element at some index `references[i]` aren't volatile even if the `references` is volatile.
    In JLS terms these are [different variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1).

Here is an execution that has a data race (the code is simplified for clarity):

```java
volatile references = [val0]; // Initially

Thread 1                  | Thread 2                | Thread 3               
----------------------------------------------------|------------------------
                          | restructure(...) {      |                        
                          |   lock();               |                        
                          |   references[0] = val1; |                        
                          |   unlock();             |                        
                          | }                       | restructure(...) {     
                          |                         |   lock();              
                          |                         |   references[0] = val2;
                          |                         |   unlock();            
                          |                         | }                      
getReference(...)         |                         |                        
  var r2 = references[0]; |                         |                        
}                         |                         |
```

Given that:

- `references[0] = val2` is actually 2 actions from JMM perspective:

  - a volatile read of `references`
  - a non-volatile write into the array's element `references[0]`
- `var r2 = references[0];` is also 2 actions from  JMM perspective:

  - a volatile read of `references`
  - a non-volatile read of `references[0]` element of the array

here is a version that reflects that:

```java
 // Initially
volatile v = [val0];

 Thread 1    | Thread 2      | Thread 3     
--------------------------------------------
             | lock();       |              
             | r3 = v;       |              
             | r3[0] = val1; |              
             | unlock();     |              
             |               | lock();      
             |               | r4 = v;      
             |               | r4[0] = val2;
             |               | unlock();    
 r1 = v;     |               |              
 r2 = r1[0]; |               |
```

Let's rewrite it in terms of [JLS actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2):

- `o` represent a `Reference<K, V>[]` object
- `v` is a `volatile` variable initialized with a reference to `o` object
- `Rv` is a volatile read
- `R` and `W` are non-volatile read and write
- value `x` in `R(..):x` or `Rv(..):x` shows the value returned by the read

```java
// Initial writes
W(o=[val0]), Wv(v=o)

 T1        | T2           | T3           
-----------------------------------------
           | Lock         |              
           | Rv(v):o      |              
           | W(o[0]=val1) |              
           | Unlock       |              
           |              | Lock         
           |              | Rv(v):o      
           |              | W(o[0]=val2) 
           |              | Unlock       
 Rv(v):o   |              |              
 R(o[0]):? |              |
```

Program order:

```
T1.Rv(v) -> T1.R(o[0])
T2.Lock -> T2.Rv(v) -> T2.W(o[0]=val1) -> T2.Unlock
T3.Lock -> T3.Rv(v) -> T3.W(o[0]=val2) -> T3.Unlock
```

Synchronization order (specific for this execution) — global order for synchronization actions:

```
Initial writes -> T2.Lock -> T2.Rv(v) -> T2.Unlock -> T3.Lock -> T3.Rv(v) -> T3.Unlock -> T1.Rv(v)
```

Synchronized-with relation (it exists between some action pairs in synchronization order):

```
Initial writes -> 1st action in every thread
T2.Unlock -> T3.Lock
```

Here are both program order and synchronized-with:

```
           W(o=[val0])                 
              ↓ (po)                   
            Wv(v=o)                    
   ┌——————————┼————————————┐           
T1 │       T2 │         T3 │           
   │          ↓ (sw)       │           
   │        Lock           │           
   │          ↓ (po)       │           
   │        Rv(v):o        │           
   │          ↓ (po)       │           
   │        W(o[0]=val1)   │           
   │          ↓ (po)       │           
   │        Unlock         ↓ (sw)      
   │          └—————————→ Lock         
   │                (sw)   ↓ (po)     
   │                      Rv(v):o      
   │                       ↓ (po)     
   │                      W(o[0]=val2) 
   │                       ↓ (po)     
   ↓ (sw)                 Unlock       
 Rv(v):o                               
   ↓ (po)                              
 R(o[0]):?
```

Together program order and synchronized-with give us happens-before:

```
           W(o=[val0])                 
              ↓ (hb)                   
            Wv(v=o)                    
   ┌——————————┤                        
   │       T2 │                       
   │          ↓ (hb)                  
   │        Lock                      
   │          ↓ (hb)                  
   │        Rv(v):o                   
   │          ↓ (hb)                  
   │        W(o[0]=val1)              
   │          ↓ (hb)                  
   │        Unlock               
   │          └—————————————┐           
   │                     T3 │      
   │                        ↓ (hb)     
   │                      Lock         
   │                        ↓ (hb)     
   │                      Rv(v):o      
   │                        ↓ (hb)     
   │                      W(o[0]=val2) 
T1 │                        ↓ (hb)     
   ↓ (hb)                 Unlock       
 Rv(v):o                               
   ↓ (hb)                              
 R(o[0]):?
```

As you can see:

1. there are conflicting accesses to `o[0]`:

   - `W(o=[val0])` in Initial writes
   - `R(o[0])` in T1
   - `W(o[0]=val1)` in T2
   - `W(o[0]=val2)` in T3
2. the read of `o[0]` in T1 is not ordered by happens-before with writes to `o[0]` in T2 and T3

This is a data race by the definition from the JLS:

> When a program contains two conflicting accesses (§17.4.1) that are not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a data race.

As a result, the read of `o[0]` in T1 in this execution can return:

1. either the latest write that happens-before it (i.e. `val0` from Initial writes)
2. or any write that is not related to it by happens-before (i.e. `val1` from T2 or `val2` from T3)

Of course, it's just one possible execution, there are many other possible executions.

Comment: this is insanely awesome. I do not know who you are, but I have seen this pattern : new user, _exceptional_ explanation of JLS chapter 17, deleted account. If that is your thing, don't stop, there are people that genuinely like to read your answers.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer!

Comment: By the way, do you draw ordering diagrams yourself, or there's a tool for this?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: can I rewrite the code in order to have one read from volatile field into a local var (i.e. synchronize on stack) and use it to avoid repeating volatile access? Won't it break JMM ...

**You can do that, but you probably shouldn't.**

**You can do that** because all writes to `references` (everywhere, not just inside `restructure()` method) occurs inside `lock()/unlock()` blocks.
As you noted, these `lock()/unlock()` blocks *enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock*.
And the built-in monitors (i.e. `synchronized`) [provide visibility and atomicity guarantees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) which are stronger than `volatile` guarantees.

**You probably shouldn't do that**, because you are asking if it will break the JMM.
It seems like you aren't sure about how the JMM works.
Meanwhile `references` inside `ConcurrentReferenceHashMap` is actually used in code with data races: for example here is data race between writes into `references[i]` in `restructure()` and reads of `references[i]` in `getReference()`:

```java
    public Reference<K, V> getReference(@Nullable Object key, int hash, Restructure restructure) {
        ...
        Reference<K, V>[] references = this.references;
        ...
        Reference<K, V> head = references[index];
        ...
    }

    private void restructure(boolean allowResize, @Nullable Reference<K, V> ref) {
        ...
        lock();
        try {
            ...
            Reference<K, V>[] restructured =
                    (resizing ? createReferenceArray(restructureSize) : this.references);
            ...
            if (!resizing) {
                restructured[i] = null;
            }
            ...
            restructured[index] = this.referenceManager.createReference(
                                    entry, ref.getHash(), restructured[index]);
            ...
        }
        finally {
            unlock();
        }
    }
```

It's possible to write code which has data races and works correctly, but you should know perfectly and in all details how exactly both the JMM and your concurrent algorithm works.
Otherwise there is a high chance to introduce one or several synchronization bugs, which are the worst: they are counter-intuitive (see [this](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind) for some examples) and cannot be unit-tested (or even reliably reproduced).

Comment: "here is data race between writes into references[i] in restructure() and reads of references[i] in getReference()"

Sorry for being that stupid, but I don't understand the race here: writing into `references` within restructure() is guarded by lock()-unlock() block, so it happens-before read from `references` in getReference(), doesn't it?

And vice-versa: reading from `references` in getReference() "sees" only the last (in terms of execution within lock-unlock) writing into `references`, doesn't it?

Comment: @SergeyTsypanov unless the reading and writing happens under the _same_ lock, this is easily a data race. JLS guarantees consistent values (in happens before order) only for pairs of execution, like the reader and the writer syncing on the same lock, the same `volatile`, etc.

Comment: @SergeyTsypanov [here is almost the same concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69293751/program-without-synchronization-order) discussed very recently.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the purpose of this optimization? Did you make a benchmark and did you run it with a profiler to determine that the code is actually a bottleneck? Please check out JMH for writing microbenchmarks.

First of all, you already have a lock. If this lock for whatever reason is contended, the overhead of context switching is a lot higher than the potential overhead of volatile variables.

Even if the lock isn't contended, it doesn't mean a volatile variable is expensive. E.g. a volatile write followed by a volatile read to a different variable on the X86 requires expensive [StoreLoad] barrier, which will prevent the CPU from executing loads till the store buffer is drained. This [StoreLoad] is needed to preserve sequential consistency; otherwise the volatile write and volatile read (different address) could be reordered.

But if you have multiple successive volatile writes which are followed by a volatile read (different variable), then on the X86 only a [StoreLoad] is needed between the last volatile write and the volatile read because stores are not reordered. So the preceding volatile writes from a CPU memory fence perspective are free. So a volatile write can be pretty cheap.

On the X86 volatile reads are quite cheap as well. On the X86 every load is an acquire load and an acquire load is sufficient to implement sequential consistency.  Keep in mind that on modern CPUs caches are always coherent and if the cacheline is already in the right state on the local CPU than a volatile read is equally expensive as a regular read from a CPU memory fence perspective. So if you would have 1 volatile read followed by 9 regular reads should probably not perform any different compared to 10 volatile reads.

The primary source of optimizations that are prevented by volatile, are optimizations done by the JIT.

For more information see this great post:
https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/

[Update]
The following loop I would certainly try to have a look at:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.references.length; i++) { // <-- !
                ref = this.references[i]; // <-- !
                //...
            }
```

I would transform it to:

```
Reference<K, V>[] localReferences = this.references;
for (int i = 0; i < localReferences.length; i++) { // <-- !
                ref = localReferences[i]; // <-- !
                //...
            }
```

I guess some code optimizations would be possible. E.g. perhaps the loop could be unrolled and perhaps multiple assignments to the localReferences could be done in parallel due to super scalar ability of modern processors. So I would definitely create a microbenchmark and see what is going on. JMH has support for various profilers and you can see the generated assembly as well.

Comment: The main purpose of the optimization is to reduce the costs related to accessing volatile field within for-loop. I'm not sure how to measure it properly and reliably, but previously similar optimizations were fruitful, see e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/2051

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: what bothers me, and I have not yet been able to fully understand the code, is when you plan to do a "multi" action on a `volatile`, like `restructure` does. For example it first reads `int restructureSize = this.references.length` and then reads again via `for (int i = 0; i < this.references.length; i++)`, if there is a write in-between these actions that does not use the same lock, they will see different results. I don't know if that matters for the code logic, but it's just weird. if there would have been a single read, right at the beginning, things would make more sense, for me. wdyt?