# Program without synchronization order

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, locking, jit

I am looking at one of the simplest examples I found and started to reason about `SO` (synchronization order) or more precise, lack of it. Consider the example below:

```
int a, b; // two shared variables 

Thread-X:

 void threadX() {
     synchronized(this) {
         a = 1;
     }
     synchronized(this) {
         b = 1;
     }
 }
```

And a reader thread, `Thread-Y`:

```
 void threadY() {
     int r1 = b;
     int r2 = a;
 }
```

For simplicity let's suppose that `Thread-Y` does the reads exactly in this order: it will for sure first read `b` and then `a` (in reverse of the writing that is).

Reading thread is allowed to see `[1, 0]` (like `b=1` happened *before* `a=1`). I think I understand also why: because there is [no synchronization order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) between the two actions, and as such there is no *happens-before* and according to the `JLS` this is a *data race*:

> When a program contains two conflicting accesses that are not ordered by a happens-before relationship, it is said to contain a data race.

Thus reading `a` and `b` are two racy reads, so seeing `b=1` and `a=0` is allowed and possible.

Now this in turn allows JVM to do the lock coarsening in the writer, so it becomes:

```
 void threadX() {
     synchronized(this) {
         a = 1;
         b = 1;
     }
 }
```

My question is, if the reader was initially written like this:

```
void threadY() {
     synchronized(this) {
         int r1 = b;
     }

     synchronized(this) {
         int r2 = a;
     }
 }
```

Would lock coarsening still be allowed? I *think* I know the answer, but I would want to hear an educated explanation too.

Comment: Lock coarsening doesn't consider the actions of other methods, because it cannot exhaustively identify all of them. Classes can be dynamically subclassed, reflection, etc. The simple answer is that the lock coarsening likely happens regardless. I've not classified this comment as an answer, because I don't consider myself "educated" enough in this domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lock coarsening (and reordering) is allowed because the synchronized readers either get ordered before or after the coarsened lock. They will never be able to see what is happening while the coarsened lock is held and hence can't observe any reordering inside the locked code.

For more information see:
https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane

Nice question btw. I was struggling with this particular example as well some time ago :)

Comment: I perfectly understand this, the reader can't acquire the lock while the writer has it, obviously. And the perceivable result from the write (after re-ordering) is of course one that makes `[1, 0]` impossible. I really get this, no questions here.

Comment: Now, considering my first example, where `[1, 0]` is possible, Shipilev says in that article: "Allowing this behavior in the model is intentional for two reasons. [...] Secondly, this enables interesting and important optimizations. For instance, in the example above, we can coalesce back-to-back locks". The part I failed to get is : "this enables", exactly what "this"? Is he talking about the fact that allowing `[1, 0]` to be seen enables such an optimization (coalesce)? Or he means that JMM allows for locks to coalesce, even if the mental model with barriers does not.

Comment: After reading probably 10 times what he wrote there, I am inclined to say that (besides the fact that I am an idiot) he really meant that while simply looking at the barriers that locks would generate, we could not coalesce the locks. But JMM totally allows that and as such would allow to re-ordering the writes, giving hardware more room for optimizations, once the coalesce has happened. The perceivable result from such a coalesce for the readers, still remains the same (as without coalesce). Took a while, but I think I get it.

Comment: "Or he means that JMM allows for locks to coalesce, even if the mental model with barriers does not. – " Correct. And that one is one of the reasons why fences are a bad mental model for the JMM.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's allowed.

---

Here is a simple explanation.

Remember that `synchronized` blocks:

1. execute atomically:

   - a thread cannot enter a `synchronized` block while another thread is holding the same lock
   - when a thread enters the `synchronized` block, then it immediately sees everything that was done in previously executed `synchronized` blocks
2. execute in a global order consistent with a program order of every thread (the synchronization order you mentioned)

In other words, `synchronized` blocks always execute atomically in a global sequential order.
Different executions can differ in how the `synchronized` blocks are interleaved, but it is always the case, that:

1. the 1st `synchronized` block from `threadX()` always executes before the 2nd one
2. same for `synchronized` block from `threadY()`

There are 6 possible interleavings:

```java
threadX          threadY           threadX          threadY             threadX          threadY       
-------------------------------    -------------------------------      -------------------------------
synchronized { |                   synchronized { |                     synchronized { |               
  a = 1;       |                     a = 1;       |                       a = 1;       |               
}              |                   }              |                     }              |               
synchronized { |                                  | synchronized {                     | synchronized {
  b = 1;       |                                  |   int r1 = b;                      |   int r1 = b; 
}              |                                  | }                                  | }             
               | synchronized {    synchronized { |                                    | synchronized {
               |   int r1 = b;       b = 1;       |                                    |   int r2 = a; 
               | }                 }              |                                    | }             
               | synchronized {                   | synchronized {      synchronized { |               
               |   int r2 = a;                    |   int r2 = a;         b = 1        |               
               | }                                | }                   }              | }             
           (Case A)                           (Case B)                             (Case C)            
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
threadX          threadY           threadX          threadY             threadX          threadY       
-------------------------------    -------------------------------      -------------------------------
               | synchronized {                   | synchronized {                     | synchronized {
               |   int r1 = b;                    |   int r1 = b;                      |   int r1 = b; 
               | }                                | }                                  | }             
               | synchronized {    synchronized { |                     synchronized { |               
               |   int r2 = a;       a = 1;       |                       a = 1;       |               
               | }                 }              |                     }              |               
synchronized { |                                  | synchronized {      synchronized { |               
  a = 1;       |                                  |   int r2 = a;         b = 1;       |               
}              |                                  | }                   }              |               
synchronized { |                   synchronized { |                                    | synchronized {
  b = 1;       |                     b = 1;       |                                    |   int r2 = a; 
}              |                   }              |                                    | }             
           (Case D)                          (Case E)                             (Case F)
```

When you merge `synchronized` blocks in `threadY()`:

```java
void threadY() {                    void threadY() {          
     synchronized(this) {                synchronized(this) { 
         int r1 = b;                       int r1 = b;        
     }                        =>           int r2 = a;        
     synchronized(this) {                }                    
         int r2 = a;                }                         
     }                                                        
 }
```

Then you effectively only leave as allowed cases where `synchronized` blocks from `threadY()` are next to each other: i.e. cases A, C and D.

Since no new possible executions appear after this optimization, then this optimization is legal.

---

For more strict and detailed explanations I would recommend:

1. "Lock Coarsening" chapter in [J. Manson's Ph.D. Thesis on JMM](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/1949/umi-umd-1898.pdf)
2. Lock Coarsening [example](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane) in an article by A. Shipilev as recommended in [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294899)

Comment: Great answer. But it must be emphasized that “execute atomically in a global sequential order” only applies to synchronization *on the same object*.

Answer (score 2):

Lock coarsening is always possible if the JVM can prove that the subsequent `synchronized` blocks will use the same object. Even the reader

```java
void threadY() {
     synchronized(this) {
         int r1 = b;
     }

     synchronized(this) {
         int r2 = a;
     }
 }
```

may get optimized too

```java
void threadY() {
     synchronized(this) {
         int r1 = b;
         int r2 = a;
     }
 }
```

But if both methods are instance methods of the same class, in other words, their `this` is referring to the same object, their execution can’t be overlapping. Therefore, even if the reads and/or the writes get reordered, the result `[1, 0]` is impossible.

Even lock elimination is allowed, as long as the execution environment can ensure that the result `[1, 0]` will never happen. One well known example would be the scenario that the object provenly is never seen by a different thread.

Comment: I really get that once you coalesce and/or the reader, `[1, 0]` is impossible. Is there a hidden message in your "their execution can’t be overlapping", because that should be obvious, right? They hold the same lock.

Comment: “their execution can’t be overlapping” means, there’s no interleaving that can be affected by reordering. The same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69305764/2711488) explains in detail. It also implies that one must be subsequent to the other in synchronization order, hence, establishing a *happens-before* relationship. Maybe, it’s kind of obvious, but still the answer to your question.

Comment: I see, thank you Holger.